# Check that exists only one entity in the values of the nested dictionary or not

Tags: python, dictionary

```py
people = {1: {'Name': 'John', 'Age': '27', 'Sex': 'Male'},
          2: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '22', 'Sex': 'Female'}}
```

I have this nested dictionary. I want to print True if all the values of Age will have a similar value. If any one of the values of Age is different, it will print False. Kindly explain how to do it?

Comment: Define "similarity" - are 27 and 22 similar ages?

Comment: If you want to check if all ages are the same then map your dict to a list of ages, convert that to a set, then test for set length == 1.

Comment: Hi, this is an example code. I want to know how to print True if one of the entity in nested dictionary like Age will have 22, 22 for both and in case if one has 22 and 27 then it's print False. Please suggest how to write the code for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the first age and then check other `Age` is equal to the first or not.

*(The first approach with `any`, when the generator face to an inequality break, so I think the first approach is faster than creating a **set of all elements** and then checking the length of `set`)*

```
people = {1: {'Name': 'John', 'Age': '27', 'Sex': 'Male'},
          2: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '22', 'Sex': 'Female'}}

# first approach
first_age = list(people.values())[0]['Age']
if any(dct['Age'] != first_age for dct in people.values()):
    print('different')
else:
    print('equal')

# second approach
# Or check with `set` and check length of `set`
if len(set(dct['Age'] for dct in people.values())) > 1:
    print('different')
else:
    print('equal')
```

Output:

```
different
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comment, you could do:

```
all_ages_equal = len({d['Age'] for d in people.values()})==1
```

Answer (score 2):

Grab any dictionary item (here, the first value). Compare all ages to the age of that item using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

```
people = {1: {'Name': 'John', 'Age': '27', 'Sex': 'Male'},
          2: {'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '22', 'Sex': 'Female'}}

v0 = list(people.values())[0]
print(all([v['Age'] == v0['Age'] for v in people.values()]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version, that isn't creating `set` or `list` first. It will *short-circuit* on first difference:

```py
people = {
    1: {"Name": "John", "Age": "27", "Sex": "Male"},
    2: {"Name": "Marie", "Age": "22", "Sex": "Female"},
}

v = iter(people.values())
print(all(a["Age"] == b["Age"] for a, b in zip(v, v)))
```

Prints:

```
False
```

Comment: Hi, what if I want to print True when age value is 22, 22 for both but false when age value 22, 27 or even some other similar value like 27, 27. I want to check the similarity only for 22. Could you help me with this as well.